# Ipython shell autocompletion for parenthesis, quotes, etc

Tags: python, ipython

Is it possible to enable autocompletion of parenthesis, quotes ... any of these `[{('"` in ipython shell? Looking at the documentation didn't indicate so.

This question is strictly referring to ipython shell, and not notebook, gui or jupyter.

Comment: I don't think there is, no.